# Merge sorting algorithm in C not working properly

Tags: c

I try to implement a Merge Sort function, However, the output (sort) becomes incorrect. I also need to explain what the function does. I tried to troubleshoot with Debug but could not find the problem. I don't know if the explanation is enough for you to help me! Note that I may not change the mergeSort argument

```
 int lessThan(int element1, int element2, Statistics* statistics);
```

True if element1 < element2

```
 int lessThanOrEqualTo(int element1, int element2, Statistics* statistics);
```

True if element1 <=
element2

```
 ElementType* arrayToSort
```

Is the array to sort

```
static void mergeSort(ElementType* arrayToSort, unsigned int size, Statistics* statistics){

    ElementType* arr = (ElementType*)malloc(sizeof(ElementType) * size);

    if (arr == NULL) {
        free(arr);
        return;
    }
    else {
        Sort(arrayToSort, statistics, arr, 0, size - 1);
        free(arr);
    }
}


static void merge(ElementType* arrayToSort, ElementType* arr, Statistics* statistics, int left, int 
right, int mid) {

    int index, Left, Right;

    for (index = left, Left = left, Right = mid + 1; lessThanOrEqualTo(Left, mid, statistics) && 
    lessThanOrEqualTo(Right, right, statistics); index++) {

        if (lessThanOrEqualTo(arrayToSort[Left], arrayToSort[Right], statistics)) {
            arr[index] = arrayToSort[Left++];
        }
        else {
            arr[index] = arrayToSort[Right++];
        }
    }

    while (lessThanOrEqualTo(Left, mid, statistics)) { 
        arr[index++] = arrayToSort[Left++];
    }

    while (lessThanOrEqualTo(Right, right, statistics)) { 
        arr[index++] = arrayToSort[Right++];
    }

    for (index = Left; lessThanOrEqualTo(index, Right, statistics); index++) {
        arrayToSort[index] = arr[index];
    }
}


static void Sort(ElementType* arrayToSort, Statistics* statistics, ElementType* arr, int left, int 
right) {

    if (lessThan(left, right, statistics)) {

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        Sort(arrayToSort, statistics, arr, left, mid);
        Sort(arrayToSort, statistics, arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge(arrayToSort, arr, statistics, left, right, mid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the smallest array possible that exhibits the problem, then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That's the usual way to solve problems like this. Pay close attention to array indexes and the limits of the arrays (as going out of bounds is a common problem).

Comment: I also recommend you use more descriptive names for your variables. `left` and `Left`? That's mighty confusing (and depending on font might even be impossible to distinguish).

Comment: You have not shown `typedef`'s for ElementType or Statistics. What effect (if any) does Statistics have on the sort/merge behavior? If the answer is "none", then remove it from your example for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Your statistics object is probably used to count how many comparisons you make. These comparisons are the comparisons that decide how two elements are related, i.e. which of two elements should be first in the sorted array. They compare two elements of `ElementType *`. I don't think you should use these functions when you compare array indices. Your code should call `lessThan` only once: when you decide which of the head elements of the two non-empty sublists comes first.

Comment: (The index comparisons are always the same, no matter which type of elements you sort. The item comparisons are important to classify your algorithm: How often do you compare elements? How often do you copy them? That information together with information of how costly or chep your comparisons or element copies are can help you decide which sorting algorithm to use.)

Comment: When you copy the sorted array back, your loop limits are wrong: `for (index = Left; index <= Right; index++)`. Your capital-letter variables have moved to one element beyond the left and right arrays. When `index == Right`, you copy over one element too many. When the subarray is at the right end of your overall array, you copy one element of garbage. You want the (locally constsnt) limits `left` and `right` here.

Comment: @MOehm do you have any hint how I can fix it in code?

Comment: I think my last comment gives a good hint. (You have mixed up the lower- and upper-case variables when copying.)

Comment: @MOehm Kind of reinforces my point about those variable. :)